# Identify which button click event set off a second form

Tags: vba

I'm working on a Visual Basic assignment that has 3 different buttons to add new data to 3 separate list boxes. All three button needs to open a second form that takes the input and store it in an array which populates the list box in the first form. I have different arrays for each of the list boxes (that's what the assignment requires). Now i need to figure out which button click event opened the second form to insert the data into the proper array. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are number of ways to pass data corresponding to button click to a user form.
Simplest may try creating some Global variable in some module, Say

Public Abc as integer
then in Button_Click event of Button 1

```
Abc=1
Userform2.show
```

make it 2 for Button 2 and so on. finally in activate event of Userform2, use Abc for selecting your data

Another way may be make a text box in Userform2, In Button click event of the Userform1 set its value And Check that text box  value at activate event of userform2, like

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
UserForm2.TextBox1 = 1
UserForm2.Show
End Sub
```

and in Activate event of Userform2

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    If Val(TextBox1.Text) = 1 Then
    'Your code here
    elseif  Val(TextBox1.Text) = 2 Then
    'Your code here
    else
    'Your code here
    End If

End Sub
```